# How to tell jq to print the content of two keys for each instance returned by aws ec2 cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, json

running aws ec2 describe-instances will return a json text similar to the following:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                  "PublicDnsName": "ec2..."
                    "VpcId": "vpc-...",
                        ...
            "Instances": [
```

I know for each "Instance" I can extract the contents of a single field, for example PublicDnsName, using jq as follows:
`jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName'` which will list the dns names for my instances
But how do I extract two or more fields and separate them by a space or comma or something? I want PublicDnsName and VpcId to be listed side-by-side for each Instance.

Specifically what I'm looking for is a list of instances where VpcId is null, undefined, or non-existent. In other words I'd like a list of my Classic instances and I need this through api so I can process the results.

Comment: I think this is a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an approach using some sample code and data from [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396925/jq-filter-to-include-unfound-select/45910774#45910774) on Stack Overflow.

To choose multiple fields you can use [Object Construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D).  E.g this filter makes an object containing just `PublicDnsName` and `VpcId` from each instance:

```
  .Reservations[]
| .Instances[]
| {PublicDnsName, VpcId}
```

If this filter is in `filter.jq` and the sample data from that other answer is in `data.json` then running

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
{
  "PublicDnsName": "xxxxxxxx",
  "VpcId": "vpc-eb09eb8e"
}
```

Once you have objects containing what you want getting the data into another format (e.g. csv) is easy.  With this filter

```
  .Reservations[]
| .Instances[]
| {PublicDnsName, VpcId}
| [.[]]
| @csv
```

and the `-r` option

```
$ jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

jq produces

```
"xxxxxxxx","vpc-eb09eb8e"
```

To add a filtering condition, e.g. VpcId is not null, add a [select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)).

```
  .Reservations[]
| .Instances[]
| {PublicDnsName, VpcId}
| select(.VpcId != null)
| [.[]]
| @csv
```

Comment: Just FYI for folks like me who are less jq-expert than jq17027: the filter can be in the command line and does not have to be in a file.